# oracle where in limitation to 1000 / hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, where-clause

Oracle knows the limitation to 1000 elements in the `where a in (..)` clause. Does this limitation also exist when using Hibernate in conjuction with Oracle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This database limitation still exists with hibernate. If you really need to have more than 1000 items in your in clause you will have to split the list yourself in the code and run the query for each block of 1000 keys, then append the result sets together.

Note this hack breaks down if your query needs to sort or otherwise aggregate the results of the query because the full set of results will only be known in the code. In this case you are better of finding another way to write the query that does not require an `IN` clause.

Comment: An alternative way would be to stick the 1000+ values in a global temporary table in the database and join the two tables. Databases are very good at joining table :)

Comment: Exactly let the database do the work! The spliting is a well know work around but one that should indicate that you need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Another alternative is to do OR on the 1000 element IN groups. This way you can "ORDER BY" on the quiry.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue and solved it by splitting it up into 100er packages of IN clause

```
select * from mytable where id in (...) or id in (...).
```

Remarks:

- make sure that you use bind variables
- make sure that the query always looks the same. This is done by filling up the IN clauses with -1 until you have 100 elements in it
- try to use always the same number of ORed in(...) so that the query always looks to same

Why you want the points above? It is so that the query optimizer can reuse the query plan.

Additional optimization:

- instead of using -1, you can just use the very last true value again. That is even a little bit better.

example: in(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, ..., 4)

Note also: we tested with various fixed numbers of elements in the in clause and observed decreased performances for a lot than 100 elements.

Comment: PS: if the sql statement which returns the values within the IN clause is known, you may also want to consider to replace your IN with an EXISTS statement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes as Hibernate will call Oracle at some stage so the limit is the lowest of the limits in Hibernate and Oracle

Hibernate does nothing special with data for an in - just passes it to the database

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a Bug in Hibernate:

http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1123