# How to retrieve records based on two equals condition for the same column?

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, oracle10g, hql

I have a table with columns ID(primary key,number), name(varchar), value(number) and key(number).I want to retrieve all the records which have key=1 and key=2. I can write the query using not equals condition(!=) but this makes the query very long.This is what I tried

```
SELECT * FROM USER_DETAILS WHERE NAME='sam' AND
KEY != 3 AND KEY != 4 AND KEY != 5 AND KEY != 6 AND KEY != 7 AND KEY != 8 AND
```

so on.Could you suggest me an Oracle query where I can retrieve the records that have key=1 and key=2 rather than checking for not equals condition.

UPDATE: As suggested in the answer I want to know if IN is supported in Hibernate

Comment: use or condition on key for value 1 and 2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673521/oracle-where-in-limitation-to-1000-hibernate

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM USER_DETAILS
WHERE
KEY=1 OR KEY=2
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM USER_DETAILS
WHERE
KEY IN (1,2)
```

Answer (score 3):

IN OPERATOR is supported in Hibernate. The query you should write to solve your problem is:

`SELECT * FROM USER_DETAILS WHERE NAME='sam' AND KEY IN (1,2)`